# Scroll horizontal ao pressionar tab

Tags: jquery

Tenho uma tabela criada a base do plugin [DataTables](https://www.datatables.net/) e com ele, fixei as quatro primeiro colunas da minha tabela que pode ter **n** colunas - as mesmas são geradas a base de uma consulta de banco - sendo que, as colunas fixas sempre estarão presentes e são informativas, possuem apenas texto. As outras colunas, possuem um `input` cada.

Como o documento possuí várias colunas, e gerado um `scroll` horizontal.

A minha intenção é que ao usuário pressionar a tecla `tab`, o `scroll` acompanhe o `input` que acabou de receber `focus`. Atualmente ele troca de `input`mas o scroll fica em posição inicial, necessitando que o usuário arraste para visualizar onde está.

Como proceder?

Comment: Podes fazer um jsFiddle com o problema?

Answer (score 0):

voce pode tentar usar esse plugin aqui do github:

https://github.com/riteshjha/scrolltab

referencia:

http://riteshsblog.blogspot.com.br/2011/09/jquery-ui-tab-scroller-plugin.html

Comment: Na verdade a minha intenção é navegar horizontalmente por inputs ao pressionar a tecla tab